# What would be a modified Hebrew version of the aaronic blessing?

Tags: pentateuch-chumash

I would like to know how to say a modified aaronic blessing to say upon oneself because I read stories of rabbis saying this upon individuals and their lives changing immensely for the better but I don’t have a rabbi to say this on me everyday etc

I can read Hebrew but don’t know how to modify the verbs or the predicates upon myself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I’m a Ben noach.

Comment: Instead of "may God bless and protect you" ... "may God bless and protect *me*"? Never heard of such a thing.

Comment: I've never heard of this, why not just repeat the verse as it is written in the Torah, like we do everyday in the Siddur anyway? But if you really must know, the verb change would be simple: יברכי יי וישמרי. יאר יי פניו אלי וחני. ישא יי פניו אלי, וישם לי שלום. "Y'varchi Hashem v'yishmari. Ya'eir Hashem panav alai v'chuni. Yisa Hashem panav alai, v'yaseim li shalom."

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Bernard and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @ezra seems to me that your version is missing some nuns. יברכני, וישמרני, ויחנני